# Button onclick move next tab in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a vertical tab and Next and Back buttons like in my react application. i want to move forward and backward tab using button click like stepper. if i click "next button" move to next tab. and the same if i click "back button" move to back tab.

and additionally, how to get data from this all tabs?

here is my tried code..

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Products() {

 const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

//Next tab button
  function getSteps() {
    return ["Shirt", "Hoodies", "Jeans", "Inner wear"];
  }

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

<Tabs
                orientation="vertical"
                variant="scrollable"
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                aria-label="Vertical tabs"
                activeStep={activeStep}
              >
                <Tab label="Shirt" {...a11yProps(0)} />
                <Tab label="Hoodies" {...a11yProps(1)} />
                <Tab label="Jeans" {...a11yProps(2)} />
                <Tab label="Inner wear" {...a11yProps(3)} />
              </Tabs>
<Form>
<TabPanel value={value} index={0}>Tab 1</TabPanel>
<TabPanel value={value} index={1}>Tab 2</TabPanel>
<TabPanel value={value} index={2}>Tab 3</TabPanel>
<TabPanel value={value} index={3}>Tab 4</TabPanel>
</Form>

{/* NEXT & SAVE BUTTONS */}

          <Grid>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
              <div>
                <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                  Saved Successfully!
                </Typography>
                <Button
                  onClick={handleReset}
                >
                  Reset
                </Button>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="secondary"
                  disabled={activeStep === 0}
                  onClick={handleBack}
                >
                  Back
                </Button>

                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  // onClick={handleNext}
                  value={value}
                onClick={handleChange}
                >
                  {/* Continue */}
                  {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Save & Update" : "Next"}
                </Button>
              </div>
            )}
          </Grid>
}
```

Comment: As per the code, it looks like you are using the material. It already has a [stepper](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/) in the framework.

Comment: @AdarshMohan Yes! am using material. but its not working. button only working but the tabs not changing

Comment: what does your `activeStep` variable do?

Comment: @AdarshMohan ```activeStep``` variable is set to move next tab using button click. but my problem is button only working, Tab is not going next.

Comment: Try it out with the [minimal example](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#DisabledTabs.js) from the website and see if that works for you.